# Change text on multiple elements on click with jquery

Tags: jquery, click

I'm working on a video page and I need to be able to change the title and description when the corresponding link is clicked. I already have it working with the title, but I'm not sure how to change the description at the same time also.

```
<h2 class="show-title"><span class="sub header">SHOW TITLE</span> <span id="episode-title">EPISODE 1</span></h2>

<p>EPISODE 1 DESCRIPTION</p>


<a href="#" onclick="playlist.play(0,0);return false;" class="change-title" data-text="EPISODE 1">video 1</a>

<a href="#" onclick="playlist.play(0,1);return false;" class="change-title" data-text="EPISODE 2">video 2</a>


$(function() {
    $(".change-title").on("click", function(e) { 
        $("#episode-title").text($(this).data("text")); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the same way, using `data-desc`

Html:

```
<h2 class="show-title"><span class="sub header">SHOW TITLE</span> <span id="episode-title">EPISODE 1</span></h2>

<p>EPISODE 1 DESCRIPTION</p>
<a href="#" class="change-title" data-desc="EPISODE 1 Description" data-text="EPISODE 1">video 1</a>

<a href="#"  class="change-title" data-desc="EPISODE 2 Description" data-text="EPISODE 2">video 2</a>
```

jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $(".change-title").on("click", function (e) {
        $("#episode-title").text($(this).data("text"));
        $('p').text($(this).data("desc"));
    });
});
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/kYTbB/

Answer (score 0):

You can likely select that `<p>` tag by using the `:first` selector

```
$('.show-title p:first')
```

https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this selector to get the `<p>` right underneath the `<h2>`:

```
$(".show-title+p").text('Description');
```

[jQuery Adjacent Selector Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to the `<p>` element and then use:

```
$("#episode-description").text('new text');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$("#episode-title").closest('h2.show-title').next().text('Description');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just modify your jquery code like this to change the description.

```
$(function() {
    $(".change-title").on("click", function(e) { 
        $("#episode-title").text($(this).data("text"));
        var text = $(this).data("text") + " DESCRIPTION"
        $("p").text(text);
    });
});
```